# iOS Obtain SSl certificate issuer and expiration information

Tags: ios

I am developing in objective-C for iOS devices. I need help in recovering SSL certificate details like issuer, expiration. Here is what my code does:

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:   (NSURLProtectionSpace*)protectionSpace
{
  if([protectionSpace.authenticationMethod      isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
  {
    // get the security chain
    CFIndex count = SecTrustGetCertificateCount([protectionSpace serverTrust]);
    for(CFIndex i = 0; i< count; i++)
    {
        SecCertificateRef certificate = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex([protectionSpace serverTrust], i);


        CFStringRef description = SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(certificate); 
        NSData* data = [(NSData*)SecCertificateCopyData(certificate) autorelease];
```

}

However, the description contains the host name. How do I interpret information from data obtained using SecCertificateCopyData? I would prefer using iOS SDK.